# What is "Transformable" in Hack language?

Tags: hhvm, hacklang

[This Facebook example](http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/install.hack.h2tp.php) shows, how Hack transpiler removes `Transformable` type hint from both `transform()` and `wonderland()` functions. Why? Is `Transformable` some built-in Hack interface or class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not anything special at all. It's just an example of an arbitrary type annotation. One of the things that the tool does is remove type annotations, such as `Transformable` (assuming you had a class called `Transformable` yourself), or `Foo`, or `Blah`, or any other class you define. There's nothing special about `Transformable` at all.

Comment: And why Hack removes type hints (they are not type `@annotation`s btw, but type hints, they are the part of php)? They do runtime type checking and they make code more readable.

Comment: The annotations Hack has are not quite like those of PHP. For example, Hack has primitive type annotations such as `int` and `string`. PHP does have class/interface annotations, but a couple work differently in Hack -- for example, an array passes a `Traversable` annotation in Hack. It would be possible to leave the intersection of what Hack and PHP support in place, but actually figuring out if a given annotation lives in that intersection can be surprisingly tricky -- so, for simplicity, we removed them all in the initial release. This is a definite area for future improvement though!